# Windows Server Active Directory in Security Account Unknown

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, security

[Active Directory Security Account Unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDlpw.png)

When I go to my Active Directory and right click on Properties and click on Security I get the following Users on in Security. Account Unknown with a SecurityIdentifier?? Is there something I am missing? I have not added them to the Active Directory before. Any ideas what this could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the SecurityIdentifier cannot be resolved to an account. This is common for accounts that are deleted, but could be for other reasons such as a domain that no longer exists or a trust that no longer exists or is broken.